# Data Structures and data representation in a given context

Tags: data-structures

I started dedicating time for learning algorithms and data structures. So my first and basic question is, how do we represent the data depending on the context. 
I have given it time and thought and came up with this conclusion.

1. Groups of same data -> `List/Arrays`
2. Classification of data [Like population on gender, then age etc.] -> `Trees`
3. Relations [Like relations between a product brought and others] -> `Graphs`

I am posting this question to know our stack overflow community thought about my interpretation of datastructures. Since it is a generic topic I could not get a justification for my thought online. Please help me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't say I've ever tried to classify data structures like this (and I also doubt that they *can* be classified this easily). I just look at the data, and consider which operations need to be supported how efficiently, then the data structure usually becomes clear from there.

Comment: For what it's worth, a tree is a type of graph.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like oversimplifying things.

The data structure we want to use depends on what we are going to do with the data.
For example, when we store records about people and need fast access by index, we can use an array.
When we store the same records about people but need to find by name fast, we can use a search tree.

Graphs are a theoretical concept, not a data structure.
They can be stored as an adjacency matrix (two-dimensional array, suitable for small or dense graphs), or as lists of adjacent edges (array/list of dynamic arrays/lists, suitable for large or sparse graphs), or implicitly (generated on the fly), or otherwise.